# MySql SELECT inside SELECT very slow

Tags: mysql, join

i'm having a trouble workign with a mysql select inside another.

This query takes 0,0007 sec:

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title
FROM node node
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('event')) AND (node.uid= 1) ))
```

But this takes 9 secs:

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title
FROM node node
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('event')) AND (node.uid= 1)  OR node.nid IN (SELECT n.nid FROM tag n WHERE n.uid='1') ))
```

Anybody knows why? both separate are really quick.

What i have to do is get some data with witch i can get some data with some joins.
I've also tryed this way but having the same problem of performance:

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title
FROM
node node
LEFT JOIN tag tag ON tag.uid = 4
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('event')) AND (node.uid  = '4') OR (tag.nid = node.nid) ))
```

Any idea? thanks

Comment: show your table structure and indices

Comment: the structure is this one:

node(status, type, uid, nid, title)
tag(uid, nid)

And the indices are only on node nid.

Both tables are 2 records

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `or` can affect query plans in bad ways.  You might try this:

```
SELECT n.title AS node_title
FROM node n
WHERE n.status = '1' AND n.type IN  ('event') AND n.uid = 1
union 
SELECT n.title
FROM node n
WHERE exists (SELECT t.nid FROM tag t WHERE t.uid = '1' and t.nid = n.nid);
```

For this to work best, have the following two indexes:

```
node(status, type, uid)
tag(uid, nid)
```

Comment: Unfortunatly it takes the same time

Comment: I suspect that `tag` is a very large table that takes time to query.  Do you have the two indexes I mention?

Comment: Nope tag is a very small tabel with two record, infact as i wrote that select takes 0.0007 too